# I want to remove an icon from a calendar in angular

Tags: angular

how to remove the calendar icon in the right side using nz-zorro in angular 7? I can't find its span in the html code but when I inspect I found it and display it none but so how to do this in the html code.

[image]

Comment: Maybe add come code or a stackblitz example?

Comment: I don't understand you, I have created the table using Ng-Zorro site but the calendar's icon isn't in the html it appears in the browser only not an icon that I've added you get me? so I can't do anything to display it none as I am not added it, it's added automatically when I create the calendar, you get me?

Comment: Try to paste your code on your question to help you